# How does Oauth 2.0 for native applications protect against spoofed redirect urls?

Tags: oauth2

In https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8252 (summarised well in https://auth0.com/blog/oauth-2-best-practices-for-native-apps) it states that there are a number of options for a native application to register a redirect uri, including loopback and "custom uri schemes".

While I understand how the PKCE mechanism protects against a MITM attack, what I don't understand is how a malicious app couldn't *also* claim the same redirect url (e.g. by decompiling the target application), thereby now being able to start a new Oauth flow, and getting an access token while claiming to be the target application (to the user).

Since there is no client secret being passed (or if there is it could have been read from the decompiled app), there is nothing to indicate to the authentication server that the client is genuine.

I'm sure I'm just missing something, hopefully someone can point me at it!

Comment: In Authorization Code Flow, the access token is never sent to the redirect URI. It is exchanged by the Relying Party using the backchannel request to the Identity Provider.

Comment: Yes but in a desktop (or native mobile) application, that backchannel request has no secret credentials (other than the temporary per-flow created PKCE), so it could be performed by any process running on the host machine.

Comment: The backchannel request is not performed by the web app. The web service requests the access token from IdP and sends it to the app.